# Discrete mathematician?

Tags: mathematics, career, jobs

I'm studying a relatively new mathematics degree called 'discrete mathematics'. This degree intertwines mathematics and computer science such that you can solve most mathematical programming problems (and more) while being able to code them (theoretical CS).

Is this something sought after by game developers? My dream is to work for a game developing company and I want to bring something to the table that nobody else brings. In my case, hopefully exceptional mathematical knowledge. You can look at it this way: If you have a mathematical problem, you'd rather want someone of my caliber than a regular mathematician as it's IT related (again, discrete mathematics). But is it needed?

EDIT: This is NOT a duplicate of the supposed duplicate. I am not your every day mathematician which is why I believe that my question has different roots. I am specifically asking the DIFFERENCE between hiring a regular mathematician and a discrete mathematician.

Comment: Well, discrete mathematics is especially used in many computer scienece subjects. Game developers like any other developers might or might not find discrete math useful. If you know about discrete math don't expect this is enough to make your next game. Yes it might be useful, but I also imagine someone with zero knowledge about what set theory or prove  by induction is still making a good game. If you are going to develop the next good AI algorithm you may need discrete math (and math in general ) so it highly depends.

Comment: This question appears off-topic because it is opinion based, and will probably be closed. Though I tried to answer it in the comments.

Comment: Obviously I know induction and set theory...

The only difference between a normal mathematician and a ''discrete mathematician'' is that normal mathematicians go deeper into real analysis and stuff like that while the discrete one goes deeper into integer solutions to computational problems, game theory etc.. You still learn everything fundamental like induction proofs..

Comment: Can someone take this off "duplicate"? It's not a duplicate.

Comment: @BjarniJóhannsson: The community has voted that your question is a duplicate. If you believe that assessment is incorrect, you must convince the community that the answer to your question will not be the virtually the same as that to the listed duplicate. Therefore, please explain how that answer doesn't address your particular concerns.

Comment: Even if not a duplicate, this is still an opinion-based question and would be closed on those grounds.  My opinion on this topic is strong and I feel is well grounded, sure, but it's by no means definitively "correct" and isn't suitable to a Q&A format.  Try gamedev.net if you want to ask about soft topics like this one.

Comment: Look, I can tell you from experience that the degree you chose isn't the main concern as long as it involves programming, what really matters is the skills you hone and your abilities. You rarely can rely on a degree to get you accepted into a serious job. You need experience.